# ImportError: undefined symbol in _...so file when using SWIG

Tags: python, c++, swig, importerror, undefined-symbol

I am using SWIG to convert a C++ code to a python code but I did not succeed to solve the following Import error. I was not able to know the source of the issue

> ImportError: /.../_RfBm.so: undefined symbol: _ZN5RNormclERSt6vectorIdSaIdEE

The RfBm.i file is given by

```
%module RfBm
%{   
  #define SWIG_FILE_WITH_INIT
  #include "RfBm.h"
%}
%include "RfBm.h"
```

The .cpp file is given by the following code

```
#include "RfBm.h"

RfBm::RfBm() {
n = 0;
H = 0.0;
gamma = 0.0;
rnorm = 0;
L = std::vector<Vector>(0);
}

double RfBm::A(int i, int j) const {
double ret = 0.0;
if((i < n) && (j < n))
    ret = cBm(i,j);
else if((i < n) && (j >= n))
    ret = cMixed(i, j-n);
else if((i >= n) && (j < n))
    ret = cMixed(j, i-n);
else if((i >= n) && (j >= n))
    ret = cfBm(i-n, j-n);
return ret;
}

double RfBm::G(double x) const {
return 2.0 * H
        * (pow(x, -gamma) / (1.0 - gamma)
                + gamma * pow(x, -(1.0 + gamma))
                        * gsl_sf_hyperg_2F1(1.0, 1.0 + gamma, 3.0 - gamma,
                                1.0 / x) / ((1.0 - gamma) * (2.0 - gamma)));
}

double RfBm::cBm(int i, int j) const {
return (i == j) ? 1.0 : 0.0;
}

double RfBm::cfBm(int i, int j) const {
double t = static_cast<double>(std::min(i,j) + 1) / n;
double s = static_cast<double>(std::max(i,j) + 1) / n;
return pow(t, 2*H) * G(s/t);
}

double RfBm::cMixed(int i, int j) const {
double ret = 0.0;
if(i <= j){
    double u = static_cast<double>(i)/n;
    double v = static_cast<double>(i+1)/n;
    double t = static_cast<double>(j+1)/n;
    ret = 2.0 * sqrt(2.0*H*n) * (pow(t - u, 0.5 + H) - pow(t - v, 0.5 + H)) / 
(1.0 + 2.0 * H);
}
return ret;
}

RfBm::RfBm(int nI, double HI, RNorm* rnormI) {
n = nI;
H = HI;
gamma = 0.5 - H;
rnorm = rnormI;
L = std::vector<Vector>(2 * n, Vector(2 * n, 0.0)); // fill with 0s first.
// Now fill the matrix L.
for (int k = 0; k < 2 * n; ++k) {
    double temp = 0.0;
    for (int j = 0; j < k; ++j)
        temp += L[k][j] * L[k][j];
    L[k][k] = sqrt(A(k, k) - temp);
    for (int i = k + 1; i < 2*n; ++i) {
        double temp = 0.0;
        for (int j = 0; j < k; ++j)
            temp += L[i][j] * L[k][j];
        L[i][k] = (A(i, k) - temp) / L[k][k];
       }
      }
}

void RfBm::generate(Vector& W1, Vector& Wtilde) {
Vector x(2 * n);
(*rnorm)(x);
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    W1[i] = 0.0;
    for (int j = 0; j <= i; ++j)
        W1[i] += L[i][j] * x[j];
}
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    Wtilde[i] = 0.0;
    for (int j = 0; j <= (i + n); ++j)
        Wtilde[i] += L[i + n][j] * x[j];
}
}

void RfBm::operator ()(Vector& W1, Vector& Wtilde) {
this->generate(W1, Wtilde);
}

std::vector<Vector> RfBm::GetA() const {
std::vector<Vector> A_mat(2*n, Vector(2*n, 0.0));
for(int i=0; i<2*n; ++i)
    for(int j=0; j<2*n; ++j)
        A_mat[i][j] = A(i,j);
return A_mat;
}
```

The commands I used for compling and linking are:

```
swig -c++ -python RfBm.i
g++ -O2 -fPIC -c RfBm.cpp -I/home/.../gsl/include
g++ -O2 -fPIC -c RfBm_wrap.cxx  -I/home/.../gsl/include
g++ -shared -o _RfBm.so RfBm.o RfBm_wrap.o -L/home/.../gsl/lib -lgsl 
-lgslcblas -lm
```

Any help? thank you.

Comment: Compile your library to solve missing symbols while linking `-Xlinker -z -Xlinker defs`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: I added -Xlinker -z -Xlinker defs but it says g++: error: Xlinker: No such file or directory. Also I think it is not a duplicate since here the issue I think is related to using SWIG. I update in the question the commands I entred for compiling and linking.

Comment: I agree with the OP that this is not a duplicate. In particular, this is a Python `ImportError`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. In fact, first I looked where _ZN5RNormclERSt6vectorIdSaIdEE is defined. It was not in RfBM.o but in another file RNorm.o

```
nm RfBm.o | grep _ZN5RNormclERSt6vectorIdSaIdEE
```

> U _ZN5RNormclERSt6vectorIdSaIdEE

```
nm RNorm.o | grep _ZN5RNormclERSt6vectorIdSaIdEE
```

> 0000000000000280 T _ZN5RNormclERSt6vectorIdSaIdEE

Then what I did is that I added that file at the end of the linking command

```
g++ -shared -o _RfBm.so RfBm.o  RfBm_wrap.o -L/home/.../gsl/lib -lgsl
-lgslcblas -lm RNorm.o
```

and it solved the issue.